# How to resolve box2d error in python?

Tags: python-2.7, box2d

I keep getting this error each time I try to create a world. How do I fix this?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Codes/test_3.py", line 3, in 
    world = b2World(gravity=(0,-10), doSleep=True)
NameError: name 'b2World' is not defined

this is the code I wanted to run.

```
    import Box2D as box2d
    world = b2World(gravity=(0,-10), doSleep=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `b2World` is a function defined in the `box2d` module, you need to specify that:

```
import Box2D as box2d
world = box2d.b2World(gravity=(0,-10), doSleep=True)
```